# Using the Amazon SageMaker Studio Image Build CLI to build container images from Studio notebooks

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to build a Docker image from SageMaker studio using the CLI described here: https://github.com/aws-samples/sagemaker-studio-image-build-cli

This should be straight forward but I'm missing something because when running the command `sm-docker build .` I have a "invalid syntax" error. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No actually I was missing the "`!`" in front of `sm-docker build .`
So `!sm-docker build .` is working.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that the command you ran is missing an exclamation mark. You ran `sm-docker build .` instead of `!sm-docker build .`

Comment: Thanks but the dash is present, if you click on the image it's in purple. The "!" was missing in front of the command, that was the problem.

Comment: Ah okay! Edited my answer so other people can be helped.